# How to make Ajax POST on PHP MVC using friendly urls?

Tags: php, jquery, http-status-code-404

I'm trying my first PHP MVC project from scratch. Everything is working fine... everything but ajax calls. When I try to POST I get a 404 error, but ONLY using AJAX; I've made the same calls using html form and it works.
This is my request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/Prueba/Bodega/createPost",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
```

and this is on my view (works if I comment the "*preventDefault*" line on js)

```
 <form action="<?=BASE_URL?>Bodega/createPost" method="POST">
```

Both methods calls the controller Bodega, function createPost  ("http://localhost/prueba/Bodega/createPost").
I think this is because of the *.htaccess* file using friendly urls but I coundn't get the solution.

Comment: pd: sorry my english writting is not as good as I wish

Comment: your are sending a `get` throw ajax not `post`. Whats the value of `BASE_URL` ?

Comment: sorry... I forgot to change GET because I was trying different ways. But GET doesn't work either.

Comment: BASE_URL = http : // localhost / prueba /

Comment: seems like a case issue: maybe try changing `/Prueba/Bodega/createPost` to `/prueba/Bodega/createPost` ?

Comment: **feel like an idiot!! it was a case issue!!** ... by the way ... it means the mvc structure works ... THANKS A LOT @KamrulKhan

Comment: no problem, glad to know I could help. I have added this as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This caused because the we server treats the request URLs in a case sensitive way. That said:

`/Prueba/Bodega/createPost` and `/prueba/Bodega/createPost` are two different URLs.

Please change `/Prueba/Bodega/createPost` to `/prueba/Bodega/createPost` and it should get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please use POST on ajax request.

Comment: that wont fix his issue